# get result using startActivityForResult()

Tags: java, android

I am trying to open my calculator and value from it then I am done here is my code for my page (where the main point is as it shows how I tried to get result)

```
TextView.OnClickListener listener = new TextView.OnClickListener()
{
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        startActivityForResult(new Intent("com.easyPhys.start.calculator"), 1);
    }
};   

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode==1)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Pass", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

this is how I tried to give a result from calculator.java:

```
mClickListener = new ButtonClickListener();
int idList[] = { R.id.button0, R.id.button1, R.id.button2,
R.id.button3, R.id.button4, R.id.button5, R.id.button6,
R.id.button7, R.id.button8, R.id.button9, R.id.buttonLeftParen,
R.id.buttonRightParen, R.id.buttonPlus, R.id.buttonDone,
R.id.buttonMinus, R.id.buttonDivide, R.id.buttonTimes,
R.id.buttonDecimal, R.id.buttonBackspace, R.id.buttonClear, R.id.buttonPow,   R.id.buttonSin, R.id.buttonCos,R.id.buttonTan,R.id.buttonAcos,R.id.buttonAtan,R.id.buttonAsin,R.id.buttonLog,R.id.buttonLog10,R.id.buttonComma,R.id.buttonToradians,R.id.buttonTodegrees };

       for(int id : idList) {
       View v = findViewById(id);
       v.setOnClickListener(mClickListener);
       }

       private class ButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener {

       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
       case R.id.buttonDone:

       if(mMathString.length() > 0);

   Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
   bundle.putString("str", mMathString.toString());

   Intent in = new Intent();
   in.putExtras(bundle);
   setResult(1, in);


new View.OnClickListener() {     
   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
   finish();
  }
   };
    break;
```

can anyone help me to understand where I went wrong as program does not close and give an answer?

Comment: Hello LG, please reduce the the amount of posted code so it can make quick sense to those who want to help you.

Comment: It's really hard to read your code, please try to improve the indentation and reduce the amount of code.

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted what you could see what I've done

Comment: So now tell us what goes wrong ? Does it crash or no result from the other activity...

Comment: It does not come back to initial page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you verified that your onClick method is being called? The reason I ask is that you show the code for onClick but you don't show that you set this for the equals button by calling setOnClickListener.

Comment: I've changed my code to how it really looks like. Do you see a mistake there?

Comment: Sorry but what you have posted doesn't clarify things much. You show a loop where you call setOnClickListener passing in mClickListener. The problem is that you don't show what mClickListener is. Further, there are now two onClick methods displayed above but there is not enough information to determine which one will be called.

Comment: You idList array does not include an entry for R.id.buttonEquals. So that button has no onClickListener. If you add R.id.buttonEquals to the array, then your ButtonClickListener onClick method will be called. Now this is not where you show a call to finish() so you will want to add that as well.

Comment: Changed code again (it is actually buttonDone). It still doesn't work. This is so confusing..

Comment: With a response like "it still doesn't work" there isn't much that I can do to help. Your original question was to ask why your Activity doesn't close when you call finish(). Yet it seems pretty clear that nothing was set up correctly to even get to the finish() call. My suggestion is that you spend some time in the debugger and find out just how far you are getting and post a new question with the specific issue you are having. Is your onClick handler being called? If so, are you able to figure out which button was selected? If so, are you actually calling finish()?

Comment: Mostly everything was the same, I just showed more code every time. If statement looks to be working, but finish () function doesn't look to do what it should do

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong :

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent("com.easyPhys.start.calculator"), 1);
```

You have to provide the current context in the constructor and specify the class name (assuming your activity class is called `modernphysics5`) :

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(modernphysics5.this, calculator.class), 1);
```

**EDIT :**

This is also wrong :

```
Intent in = new Intent(mMathString.toString());
setResult(1,in);
```

This is not the right use of the `Intent(String)` constructor. If you want to send a string with your intent you should use a `Bundle` :

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("str", mMathString.toString());

Intent in = new Intent();
in.putExtras(bundle);
setResult(1, in);
```

Comment: but it does not come back after I press "equal" button

Comment: Still the same effect. Should I use something else instead of finish()?

Answer (score 0):

try putting your code from onActivityResult before super.onActivityResult

second remark is that you normally check for your requestCode to be the same, not for your response-code as the response may come from somewhere else (just a minor one though;))

EDIT: Put an onClickListener on your btnEquals

Comment: The problem is that calculator does not close after pressing "equal" button. And what is bad with my response code?

Comment: nothing is really bad with response code, but you check in onresponse for what your response code is: normally what you do is: you check for requestCode, but as I said: this is a minor one...it is only a detail which becomes important if you have multiple responses coming in on which you need to react differently

Answer (score 0):

If there is a need to answer this question any more, try using:  CLASS_NAME.this.finish(); (CLASS_NAME being the name of your class that you would like to return from).